# How do I get that fading blue highlight (from 3.0+) on an object?

Tags: android

I have an ImageView (although I'd like to know how to do it for any View object) that is clickable. Right now, clicking it feels a little unfulfilling, because there's none of that blue highlight users are accustomed to seeing.
The blue highlight is ALL over the OS, so I doubt Google used boilerplate code in every UI element that has it. Is there a simple way to apply it to a View object?

In case I wasn't clear enough, I'm referring to the blue glow that goes on a list item/button when you put your finger on it, and fades away when you take your finger off.

Comment: Perhaps you want to apply the new "Holo" theme? http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/01/apply-android-holo-theme.html

Comment: Not quite, I'm already using the Holo theme. I'm looking for a way to get the highlight on my objects.